# Better way to write this request spec?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, capybara

I have a request spec that looks like this:

```
describe "Registering from the main page" do
  before(:each) do
    fill_in "username","my_username"
    fill_in "password","my_password"
    fill_in "password_confirmation","my_password"
    click_button "Register"
  end

  it "should have created a new user" do
    User.count.should == 1
  end

  it "should have changed the message on the homepage" do
    find("#element").value.should == "You registered!"
  end

  # ... other tests like this
end
```

First question, how can I make sure I have 0 users before submitting the form?

Second, that `before` doesn't quite seem right to me, even though it does the job. Is there another way of writing the tests for this whole registering use case? Perhaps reformulate the before part somehow, or is it acceptable the way I'm doing it?

UPDATE: I changed the `before(:all)` to `before(:each)` because tests started to fail. The body of the response seems to be incomplete when I'm using `before(:all)`. Do you happen to know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can can use the `change()` matcher so as not to have to worry about what the count is beforehand:

```
lambda { click_button("Register") }.should change{ User.count }.by(1)
```

If you really want it to specifically go from 0 to 1, you can do this:

```rb
lambda { click_button("Register") }.should change{ User.count }.from(0).to(1)
```

To answer the question about `before(:all)` and `before(:each)`, `before(:each)` will get called once before each example (`it` block), whereas `before(:all)` gets called **only once** before all examples in the `describe` block. This is why `before(:all)` is generally not recommended, since, if any of your examples change something about the initial state, later examples will be affected.

Comment: What about the fact that it's in a `before(:each)` block? Is there a way to get it out of there?

Comment: Other than the line `click_button "Register"`, I think that code is in the right place. It's preparation for testing the registration, and it seems it needs to be there for all your examples, so `before(:each)` is good.

Comment: Also, added something to address the `before(:all)`/`before(:each)` question.

Answer (score 2):

You can also write it as

```
expect { click_button "Register" }.to change(User, :count).by(1)
```

Have a look at this link: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-up?version=3.2#sec:tests_for_user_signup